# Pyinstaller builds file but chokes on certain .dlls

Tags: python, dll, pyinstaller

When I run my py program it works the way I intended it to. If I am on a Linux box and build an executable using Pyinstaller, it builds without issue and executes without issue. I have scoured the Pyinstaller docs, git, etc. none of the posted fixes helped

I am still very new at python and feel like it might be a simple fix and might be over thinking the issue

Why can I no build a functional .exe on a windows based system using pyinstaller?

Windows 10 system

Pyinstaller version 3.2

Python version 3.5.2

This is a GUI program using appJar which is also up to date.

The file does build, but errors "Could not execute script"

**EDIT**
Not sure if this is best to edit in line like this but...
So studying the output and making adjustments, the issue seems to be appJar.py. For some reason it is missing assets, I am looking into it. The trouble is that I am still not used to looking at this kind of output and am not sure where to start.

```
C:\Users\_User_>C:\temp\fileCreatorGUI\fileCreatorGUI.exe
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "F:\Users\_User_\python_working\fileCreatorGUI.py", line 73, in <module>
    app = gui()
  File "C:\Users\_User_\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python35\lib\site-packages\appJar\appjar.py", line 509, in __init__
    self.topLevel.wm_iconbitmap(self.appJarIcon)
  File "C:\Users\_User_\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python35\lib\tkinter\__init__.py", line 1716, in wm_iconbitmap
    return self.tk.call('wm', 'iconbitmap', self._w, bitmap)
_tkinter.TclError: bitmap "C:\temp\fileCreatorGUI\appJar\resources\icons\favicon.ico" not defined
Failed to execute script fileCreatorGUI
```

**Edit 2**
See answer below, but I was barking up the wrong tree on this one,

---

The Pyinstaller output chokes on the .dll's:

```
api-ms-win-core-console-l1-1-0.dll
api-ms-win-core-datetime-l1-1-0.dll
(There are like ~40 of these)
```

I added those .dll's to the python path, I declared them in the bianaries in the .spec file.

here is a truncated log:

```
    2414 WARNING: Can not get binary dependencies for file: C:\Windows\system32\api-
ms-win-crt-stdio-l1-1-0.dll
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:\Users\_USER_NAME\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python35-32\lib\site-pa
ckages\PyInstaller\depend\bindepend.py", line 695, in getImports
    return _getImports_pe(pth)
  File "C:\Users\_USER_NAME\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python35-32\lib\site-pa
ckages\PyInstaller\depend\bindepend.py", line 122, in _getImports_pe
    dll, _ = sym.forwarder.split('.')
TypeError: a bytes-like object is required, not 'str'
2423 WARNING: Can not get binary dependencies for file: C:\Windows\system32\api-
ms-win-crt-heap-l1-1-0.dll
```

I tried the fix listed here: 
https://github.com/pyinstaller/pyinstaller/pull/1981

but it did not seem to make a difference.

Someone recommended adding the `sys.path.insert()` route but it did not make a difference either way
I also tried this in a VM with windows 7, clean install, no change. My next step is to try to use Wine in Debian, but I don't really want to go that route. Any help would be appreciated. Thank you

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Turns out this was an appJar/packaging issue, the pyinstaller was not looking in the correct directory for the assets. per the dev of appJar, I commented out two lines of code in the appJar.py, lines 508-509:

```
if self.platform == self.WINDOWS:
    self.topLevel.wm_iconbitmap(self.appJarIcon)
```

More on the specifics here: https://github.com/jarvisteach/appJar/issues/84
I probably can fix this by using the --path argument with pyinstaller but for the moment, the issue is fully resolved